# Humidity Levels

Tags: hvac, basement, maintenance, humidity, air-quality

What is a healthy and safe humidity level that I should try to keep my house at?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the winter it is 30 to 40 percent in cold climates.  During the summer, indoor humidity levels should be kept below about 65 percent to minimize the potential for mold growth and below about 50 percent to minimize dust mites.

See this article for some more great information on humidity levels: [Keep Your Home Healthy](http://www.ag.ndsu.edu/pubs/ageng/structu/ae1204w.htm)

Comment: Cannot stress how important it is to be under the mold cut-off! (60-65%)

Comment: Aforementioned article in PDF: http://www.ag.ndsu.edu/homemoisture/documents/pdf/homehealthy-lesson.pdf